# Getting data from API to SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, weather

I have run into a problem with weather API from OpenWeatherMap. I am getting data as a JSON object. I am able to present them in a view, unfortunately I don`t know how can I store them to my local database. My goal is to store them in the database so I can use them in specific model.

My model:

```
public virtual Humidity Humidity { get; set; }

public Object getWeatherForcast()
    {
        string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Aalborg&APPID=MY APPID &units=imerial";

        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);
        return jsonContent;


    }
```

My Controller

```
public JsonResult GetWeather()
    {       
        Plant weath = new Plant();
        return Json(weath.getWeatherForcast(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

My view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.get("@Url.Action("GetWeather","Weather")", function (response) {
            console.log(response);
                $("#name").text(response.name);
                $("#temp").text(response.main.temp);
                $("#humidity").text(response.main.humidity);
        });
    });
```

I am trying to equal lets say humidity from API to the field from one of my models, lets say water:

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Wat,TimeRec")] Water water)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            water.TimeRec = DateTime.Now;
         //I think it should be done here
            water.Wat = Json.response.main.humidity;
            db.Entry(water).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Plants, "Id", "Name", water.Id);
        return View(water);
    }
```

It would be helpful if someone could point me in right direction

Thanks a lot

Comment: what problem specifically are you running into?

Comment: I don`t know how can I save specific data from Json object, lets say humidity to database. I try it with following code 

`water.Wat = Json.response.main.humidity;
            db.Entry(water).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();`

type is not valid in the give context